# VBA WebScraping How To select value from a drop dropdown box

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch some data from a website, to do this first fill the form controls and then click on the button, however I am not able to select value from the drop down box, please help me to achieve this task.

```
Sub extract_data_from_MonsterIndia()

    Dim objIE                   As Object
    Dim myjobtype               As String
    Dim myexperience            As Integer
    Dim mycity                  As String
    Dim r                       As Integer
    Dim c                       As Integer

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    myjobtype = "VBA Developer"
    myexperience = "5"
    mycity = "Delhi/NCR"

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("http://www.monsterindia.com")

        While .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        .Document.getelementsbyname("fts").Item.innerText = myjobtype
        .Document.getelementsbyname("exp").Item(0).innerText = myexperience    'This line is not working
        .Document.getelementsbyname("lmy").Item.innerText = mycity
        .Document.getelementsbyname("submit")(0).Click

        Do While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    End With

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Document.getelementbyid("selExp").InnerText = "n"
.Document.getelementbyid("selExp_val").Value = "n"
```

[image: Relevant DOM]

In this case we are not actually dealing with the typical 'dropdown' menu `<select>` tag. This menu uses a list of options and some DOM manipulations that stores the value inside of the `<input>` tag's value attribute. Therefore, we can simply modify the value attribute under that tag.

The code I have posted uses the id of the tag (which there should only ever be one id) and we manipulate that specific element's value attribute using .value.

Editing the innerText is not explicitly necessary because it is superficial (the server will most likely not receive or use that data)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for replay, however it is not working, giving me an error message "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Thanks
Kashif

Comment: I updated the code. Let me know if it works for you. I think I misread the DOM the first time I looked at it somehow.

Comment: Hi Code G,

Thank you so much it is working fine.

Many many thanks to you :)

Thanks
Kashif

Comment: You're welcome. And since you appear new, if this answer or any other one solves your issue in the future, please mark the best answer as accepted using the green check mark.